# Looking for a word describing someone who is "too nice"

Tags: single-word-requests

"Too nice", as in constantly trying to please others, perhaps motivated by a fear of being disliked, and typically this person is nice or overly excited when others wouldn't be.

Is there a word for this behavior? (That isn't kiss-ass...)

Example use: "I find his ???? personality off-putting."

Thanks!

Comment: *Saintly. Goody-two-shoes. Overly pleasing. Over-enthusiastic.*

Comment: *Pushover* or *sucker* ?

Comment: I think members should be more severe about questions.

Comment: obsequious, ingratiating, sycophantic, fawning

Comment: Or *brown nosing*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**unctuous**: excessively or ingratiatingly flattering; oily.  *He seemed anxious to please but not in an unctuous way.*

-- Edit --  I had another idea.

**glad-handing**: The urban dictionary defines *glad hand* as a "smarmy individual who hugs a lot, gets too close and is generally over friendly in an irritating way."  The problem with this is it describes behavior, not personality, as you wanted.

Comment: In that sense, **hypocrite**

Comment: As you noted on glad-handing, this is all personality.

Comment: @Ceems - With a little work, it might fit together -- *So-and-So is useless as a principal (=director of a school).  He spends the whole day glad handing instead of leading and solving problems*.  But if *unctuous* isn't too fancy for your context, I think that really is the most apt word for your question.

Comment: You include _smarmy_ in the definition of glad-handing. It would be an answer in itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is my made up word for it: nicey

Used in a sentence: Of course Todd would do everyone's assignment, he is such a nicey!

Comment: "nicey", while applicable, is a little too juvenile for my specific use case.